# Accessing views between different areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two different Areas (User & Report) and they have two views (Login & Index) respectively.

What I am trying to do is on successful login user should be redirected to Report/Index page but its not working.

Its always inside User area only. Can some one point out what needs to be corrected here. Thanks!!! Help will be appreciated...

[image]

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {    
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (user.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Report/Report/Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
                }
            }
            return View(user);
        }
      }

public class ReportController : Controller
{
    // GET: Report/Report
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "DWP_MVC.Areas.User.Controllers" }
            ).DataTokens.Add("area", "User");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Report",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Report", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "DWP_MVC.Areas.Report.Controllers" }
            ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Report");
        }
    }

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "User_default",
                "User/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Report_default",
        "Report/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RedirectToAction()` call must include the area name if you are using areas in your MVC structure.

In your example the following code would work:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Report", new { area = "Report" });
```

As an aside, if you wish to redirect from one area to a controller/view which is not within the Area folder, you can utilize `area = ""`

Comment: thanks it worked. One more question I have an ActionLink in _Layout.cshtml page @Html.ActionLink("Log In", "Login", "User", new { Area = "User" }, new { }) This should redirect to login page but all I get is resource not found although the Url is xxx/User/User. Any idea?

Comment: I think you are passing the "Login" parameter twice? I do not know your full setup and any custom URL handling, but I would suggest trying `@Html.ActionLink("Login", "User", new { area = "User" })` provided your actionName is 'Login', controller is 'User'. Also why the second new {} ? Does the method require an empty object?

Comment: Parameters: First is the display name, second is the actionName, third is controller, fourth is area and last is for htmlAttributes. It can be null as well. And I have no custom routes other than mentioned in the main question. Also _Layout.cshtml is under root/Views/Shared

Comment: These parameters seem correct, and look like they are in the right order. Try rebuilding your application? Otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, did all nothing works. Strange part is I cant directly access Login page i.e. using URL xxx/User/User/Login causes page not found and when the default route kicks in then URL xxxx displays login page. Strange indeed...

Comment: Why not create a LoginController in the User area with an Index action?  That way your url would just be /User/Login